# Convert Array[Row] to DataFrame in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` to a `DataFrame`.
Could anyone suggest me a better way?

I tried to first convert it into `RDD` and then tried to convert it into `Dataframe` , but when I perform any operation on the `DataFrame` , exceptions are shown.

```
val arrayOfRows = myDataFrame.collect().map(t => myfun(t))
val distDataRDD = sc.parallelize(arrayOfRows)
val newDataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(distDataRDD,myschema)
```

Here `myfun()` is a function which returns `Row (org.apache.spark.sql.Row)`.
The contents in the array is correct and I am able to print it without any problem.

But when I tried to count the records in the `RDD`, it gave me the count as well as a warning that one of the stage contains a task of very large size.I guess I am doing something wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in the first line. `collect` returns an Array while `map` is a method that operates on DataFrames/RDDs.

Try `val arrayOfRows = myDataFrame.map(t => myfun(t)).collect()` instead.

Comment: I am getting this error when i change the order   **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable**

Comment: arrayofRows is actually of type DataFrame so there's no need for lines 2 and 3 (sc.parallelize accepts RDDs and not DataFrames, which is the reason behind the new exception)

Comment: I am getting the error as soon as I enter the first line `val arrayOfRows = myDataFrame.collect().map(t => myfun(t))`

Answer (score 1):

```
case class PgRnk (userId : Long , pageRank: Double ) 
// create a case class 

sc.parallelize(pg10.map(r1 => PgRnk(r1.getLong(0), r1.getDouble(1)))).toDS() 
// convert into a dataset, sc.parallelize converts the array into a RDD, and then to DS
```